# How to install Intel Open Image Denoiser node on Blender 2.79

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I'm using Blender 2.79 and Cycles Render. And I'm rendering on 2.81 on Cycles Render with Intel denoiser, but 2.81 crashes. Please help me to use this denoiser on 2.79. Help me to install Intel denoiser for Blender 2.79.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't install it like a plugin. ODIN is a [c++ library](https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn/tree/master/core) so the only way you'll get it into Blender 2.79 is compiling the source code [using this commit](https://developer.blender.org/D4304) by yourself. However, question is: *Why it shouldn't crash on 2.79?* TBH, I don't think this is worth the hassle (probably takes hours trying to compile it properly).

Answer (score 1):

There is *Theory Studios* build with OIDN in trunk. AFAIK it's the latest 2.79b version. Grab it here:
https://blender.community/c/graphicall/dbbbbc/

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 19.10